# Enable wifi option not showing in fresh install of ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I have just installed Ubuntu on my PC but there is no option for enabling WiFi. My PC is Lenovo g405.

`lsusb` gives the following output:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129
Card Reader Controller Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux
Foundation 2.0 root hub Bus 004 Device 002: ID 105b:e065 Foxconn
International, Inc. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth module Bus 004 Device 001: ID
1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub Bus 001 Device 002: ID
174f:114f Syntek  Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation
2.0 root hub Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root
hub Bus 005 Device 002: ID 090c:1000 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan
(formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) Flash Drive Bus 005 Device 001: ID
1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and `lspci` gives:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Root Complex 
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini [Radeon HD 8210] 
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP Audio
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 0 
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1 
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1 
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 01) 
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] 
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 39) 
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 39) 
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 39) 
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 3a) 
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 02) 
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11) 
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 1 
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 2 
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 3 
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 4 
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Function 5 
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet (rev 10) 
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **:-)** Could you open a Terminal [Ctrl][Alt][T] and copy-paste `lsusb && lspci` in there and hit [Enter] and then [edit] your question and provide the output of that in there?

Comment: @Fabby Please check my edited question.

Comment: but that did not solve my problem.

Comment: In 4 minutes???  Please read the entire thread and then come back and tell us exactly where you got stuck and we'll re-open,

Comment: i had tried that earlier and came here

Comment: Please run the terminal command: `sudo modprobe wl` If you get "Required key not available," then check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules

Comment: I do not have internet connections then how am I supposed to run sudo apt-get commands in those solutions.

Comment: Ok i'll post where I stuck exactly.

Comment: Please get a network cable and plug it in while you're solving the WiFi issue...  It's just easier that way, sorry!

Comment: I solved it in different way.